# Three.js - How to set position relative to an object's position and direction?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to get my 2nd object to be directly behind (-distance) my 1st object that has been rotated.

Let's say I have 2 objects:

```
var object1 = new THREE.Object3D();
object1.position.set(5, 10, 53);
object1.rotateX(1);
object1.rotateY(1.5);


var distance = 20; //place object2 20 units behind object1
var object2 = new THREE.Object3D();
object2.position.set( /*position object2 right behind object1 -distance */);
object2.lookAt(object1);
```

In this instance, how do I place `object2` directly behind `object1` which has been rotated?

Visual 2D example. Not to scale

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Do it like so:

```js
let camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
  camera.position.set(5, 10, 55);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry();
  const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

  const mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh1.position.set(5, 10, 53);
  mesh1.rotateX(1);
  mesh1.rotateY(1.5);
  scene.add(mesh1);

  const mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh2);

  const v1 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1).applyQuaternion(mesh1.quaternion);
  mesh2.quaternion.copy(mesh1.quaternion);
  mesh2.position.copy(mesh1.position).add(v1.multiplyScalar(-2));

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.target.copy(mesh1.position);
  controls.update();

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.128/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.128/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

The idea is to apply the rotation of `object1` to `object2` and also use it to compute the position behind `object1`. This is done by applying the rotation to a vector which is then scaled by a distance value (in the above case `-2`) and then added to `object1`'s position value.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific use-case, you can add `object2` to `object1`, and simply set `object2`'s position to a single-axis value of the distance you want, in whatever axis serves as "behind" `object1`.

```js
// given: object1, object2
// assuming: the meshes' "forward" direction is locally +Z, both "up" are +Y

scene.add( object1 )

object1.add( object2 )

object2.position.z = -distance
```

#### A few clarifications:

> the meshes' "forward" direction is locally +Z

This is important for determining what "behind" means. For example, a car would have the headlights pointing in the +Z direction.

> both "up" are +Y

This is another aspect of the model orientation. If the "up" direction of both models is +Y, then both are "upright" relative to each other. This is like saying that for two cars, both of their roofs are oriented in the +Y direction.

#### How this works:

Given that both meshes are--in their base orientation--oriented the same, then what you can do is manipulate `object2` relative to `object1`. You can do this by making `object2` a child of `object1`, which means `object2` will now perform its transformations within `object1`'s local space, rather than world space. This is possible because `Mesh` is a derivative of `Object3D`, which is a generic 3D container in three.js. As a child, `object2` automatically inherits `object1`'s transformations, so as you move/rotate `object1`, `object2` will follow.

#### How this *won't* work

You can continue chaining children to your heart's content, but at some point you might want to make one of the objects in your chain do something relative to an external or global object. Unwinding the transformations will take a few extra steps before you can perform your desired actions.